# Debian - X11 not displaying until switching VTs

Tags: x11, xorg

I am trying to make my own very light Debian-based system, using Fluxbox as window manager and Slim as login manager.

I just added Slim but I had a problem before that, being that X11 worked correctly once or twice, then I rebooted and all I'd get would be a black screen.

I then found out that switching VT and back to X11 would show me what I want: Fluxbox.

Adding Slim, I still get a black screen at boot, but then if I switch VT and back, I'll get it to display properly.

Has anyone ever run into such a problem? I've looked at X11 logs and do see errors but none of these leads seem to give me anything good. I've looked into the "xmodmap not found" issue, the "failed to read" one... to no avail.

Thanks for your help!